# Excel VBA Remove Duplicates when Workbook Protected even though cells are not locked

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2010 -
I have a worksheet labeled "DATA1" and in this example the entire workbook has been protected for the users to use only certain cells. Even though I have columns ("L:N") that I want to Remove Duplicates on Un-Locked, the code will not remove duplicates. The method of unprotecting the whole workbook and re-protecting is not a viable option given all the actions the code must go through. FYI: When the Administrator has the entire file unprotected, the code runs flawlessly.

It hangs on the following code with this error message - "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L1:N200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
    Header:=xlYes
```

After unlocking the entire sheet, even thought the entire workbook is protected, it now stops on the first line of code:

```
Sheets("DATA1").Range("List_FTE_Names").ClearContents
```

Here is my code:

```
 Sub mcr_FTE_Names()

 'Clear contents in the FTE Names columns for a clean slate
 Sheets("DATA1").Range("List_FTE_Names").ClearContents

 'Copy FTE Names columns from Labor Forecast Detail
 Sheets("Labor Forecast Detail").Range("List_FTE_Names_Forecast").Copy

 'Paste Special Values of data just copied
 Sheets("DATA1").Range("List_FTE_Names").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

 'Remove Duplicates
 Sheets("DATA1").Range("List_FTE_Names").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
    Header:=xlYes

 'Sort Alphabetically
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("L2:L800") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("M2:M800") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N2:N800") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("List_FTE_Names")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply

 End With

 MsgBox "Your Resources have been consolidated and alphabetized," & vbNewLine & "you will now proceed back to the Home page."
 Sheets("Home").Select
 Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Any thoughts and/or direction would be most appreciated.
Thank you for looking.

Here is my ProtectAll_Admin() code if it helps:

```
Sub ProtectAll_ADMIN()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pWord1 As String
Dim pWord2 As String

For Each ws In Worksheets
   If ws.ProtectContents Then
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & " is already protected.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
   End If
Next ws

' To Hide all rows and columns for editing
Call mcr_HideRowsColumns_ADMIN

pWord1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password")
If pWord1 = "" Then Exit Sub

pWord2 = InputBox("Please re-enter the password")
If pWord2 = "" Then Exit Sub

'Make certain passwords are identical
If InStr(1, pWord2, pWord1, 0) = 0 Or InStr(1, pWord1, pWord2, 0) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You entered different passwords. No action taken!"
   Exit Sub
End If

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Protect Password:=pWord1
   'ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    ws.Protect AllowFiltering:=True
Next

MsgBox "All Sheets have been Protected" & vbNewLine & "and the File is ready for the PM."

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if workbook.protect locks the cells.  I thought it only prevented any new sheets from being added or moved around.  Are you sure that particular sheet is not protected?

Comment: @JohnMuggins - The code to protect the workbook is For Each ws In Worksheets
     ws.Protect Password:=pWord1
     ws.Protect AllowFiltering:=True
However, I have plenty of unlocked cells for the Managers to enter in time for their FTE's. I can even edit the cells that are mentioned above, because they are unlocked. It is baffling me beyond belief. I don't want to create workaround that is hideous to the manager or the Admin.

Comment: In protected sheet many options are disabled like data validation, filter, remove duplicate, etc. In you VBA code you can use Sheets("DATA1").Unprotect Password:="pWord1"  and Sheets("DATA1").Protect Password:="pWord1"

Comment: @RamAnuragi Great Thought, I had that, but when the Admin clicks the button to lock everything, the message box tells the Admin that it is already protected. Hence, it makes it a hack job. You couldn't have known my overall protection code. Since, you didn't that was a clever response.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea why a similar problem would occur in `Shared` workbook? Unshared, the RemoveDuplicates line works fine...Shared gives me the 1004 on that line. The workbook is not protected in any way...just shared to enable multiuser, simultaneous editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using the userinterfaceonly method when the worksheets are protected. ie

```
for each ws in workbook
    ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
next ws
```

This code only locks it for the users  but not vba.  You won't need to worry about protecting and unprotecting sheets in your vba code.

Comment: I added that ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True and that put me into a infinite loop of asking me in system message box to Unprotect.

Comment: I actually strung that together and it actually works John, Thank YOU!

      For Each ws In Worksheets
     ws.Protect Password:=pWord1, AllowFiltering:=True,  UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Comment: I learned that trick from Cpearson many years ago.  Very helpful.  But yes, the code I wrote required all the worksheets to be unprotected first before the code is run.  You could simply add a line "ws.unprotect" directly above the "ws.protect userinterfaceonly:=True" in order to avoid the errors.